# Color del texto en CKEditor

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ckeditor

Estoy usando `CKEditor` con `Angular2` para editar/modificar un parámetro que tengo guardado en la base de datos. Todo funciona correctamente, excepto que cuando me carga el texto de la base en el `CKEditor`, no lo veo porque viene con la letra blanca por default.

¿Cómo puedo configurar el `CKEditor` para que automáticamente el color del texto sea negro?

Esta es la configuración que tengo:

En el HTML:

```
<ckeditor
    [(ngModel)]="ckeditor_Notif_Register"
    [config]="{uiColor: '#F0F3F4',
               extraPlugins: 'divarea'}"
    debounce="500">
</ckeditor>
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado si la configuración es correcta y/o si tienes errores en consola?

Comment: La consola no marca ningun error. La configuracion es correcta en cuanto a lo básico, por lo menos en lo que yo entiendo y en base a los ejemplos que encontré...pero en ningun ejemplo pude ver como configurar el color del texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno...me respondo a mi mismo...hay que agregar el siguiente estilo en el .css para que el fondo sea blanco y el color de letra negro.

```
.cke_contents {
    background-color:white;
    color: #000;
}
```

Bastante bobo, pero no lo podia encontrar. Lo dejo por si a alguien le hace falta.